# Java Reverse Node Stringlist

Tags: java, nodes, reverse

i am new to java coding and i hope you guys are able to help :)

What i am trying to achieve.

> **A**->B->C->...
>
> A
>
> ---
>
> A->**B**->C->...
>
> B->A
>
> ---
>
> A->B->**C**->...
>
> C->B->A

Here are my codes for this, hope you guys are able to help me find out why i keep getting an empty list.

```
public StringList reverse(){

    Node cursor = head;

    String temp;
    while(cursor!=null){
        temp = cursor.getElement();
        head = new Node(temp,head);
        cursor = cursor.getNext();

    }

    return new StringList();}
```

Thanks for the replies and answers managed to get it to work :) heres the code for future reference of others.

public StringList reverse(){
        StringList newList = new StringList();

```
    Node cursor = head;

    String temp;

    while(cursor!=null){
        temp = cursor.getElement();
        newList.head=new Node(temp,newList.head);
        cursor = cursor.getNext();

    }

    return newList;}
```

Comment: You are returning a new StringList at the end of the function.

Comment: Missing lot of code no? Where does `head` come from ? You do nothing with your new `head`, certainly should be in the return somehow.

Comment: Thank you sir, but how am i able to add new nodes to the new stringlist? and if i remove new StringList, what would be the return value ?

Answer (score 0):

First the answer to your question: You're getting an empty list because that's what `new StringList()` presumably returns. (It's hard to be sure because you haven't shown us your `StringList` class, and it's not part of the standard java library). The value your method returns does not appear to be in any way affected by the code the precedes it. Again, I can't say for sure becuase your variable `head` is not local to the method, and so it could be referenced by the `StringList` constructor. You probably really want to pass a `StringList` as a method parameter and then work with its `head` value or something, rather than accessing some variable in an outer scope. Then your return value should be a `StringList` constructed from the final value of `head` - unable to say how without seeing `StringList` and `Node`.

The main code of your method almost correctly reverses a linked list of String values. The only problem is that you need to set `head = null` after `cursor = head`. As it stands you'll end up with your reversed list followed by the original (e.g. C, B, A, A, B, C). (Assuming your `Node` class acts in the obvious ways.)

I'm assuming this is an assignment or a learning exercise, otherwise see Java's standard `List` interface and its implementations, and `Collections#reverse`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a lot of thing.

First you want to reverse a `StringList` but your `reverse` method doesn't take one as a parameter.

Second you use a `head` variable (certainly the head of the StringList? Would be better if we knew what the StringList methods/attributes are) without having it initialized anywhere.

Third, you create a Node (Here again how is defined a `Node` ?) but never use it after.

Finally you return an empty `StringList`, which will only help having an empty `StringList` whatever marvelous computing you did before.

You should (Given the few information we have):

- Get the StringList as a Parameter of the method
- Create a new `StringList` let's call it resultList
- Get the head from your list, and create a new node
- Link your item in reverse order
- Put your new node in the resultList
- Return the resultList